# parallelStream throwing Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null

Tags: java, rest, java-8, java-stream

I have created a REST API Service within which I am using Java8 parallelStream like as shown below

```
employeesDetails = employeesDetailsList.parallelStream().map(getEmployeesDetails ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am using parallelStream because it needs to iterate huge records and marshall it to a different response. The API is working fine, but the problem is lets say the REST API takes 1 min time to execute successfully. If one hits the same REST API service multiple times at the server side its executing multiple times and throwing exception `Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null`

Can anyone please help me on this. Also like to know whether parallelStream  is the correct choice for this scenario

Comment: Please show a complete example and the complete stack trace.

Comment: TimeoutExceptions you're looking at are not relate to `parallelStream`. Look at the API response times and ensure reduced network latencies to achieve whatever you're trying to. Or else increase the timeout in worst case.

Comment: `parallelStream` is not appropriate here, as it doesn't given you enough control over the number of concurrent requests you are making to your REST server -- it is likely that you are overwhelming it.

Comment: @tgdavies but when I use normal `stream()` then it is taking around **4 min**

Comment: You should use an executor service with a known number of threads, rather than a parallel stream. Not everything in Java has to be done with a stream. Also, make sure all requests to the REST server are handled together, not separately for each hit on your service.

Comment: @RealSkeptic but executor service also are multi threaded which runs parallely right, so what's the befenit it does have over parallelStream

Comment: Right, but **you have control on the number of threads**, thus the number of concurrent accesses to the REST service, which you don't have in `parallelStream`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did'nt get that....you mean we have give the control over allocation no of threads for to complete my task.

Comment: I mean you have to make sure you don't call the `REST` server more than X times concurrently. And make sure you decide on the correct X.

Comment: since the call is from UI, I cant guarantee the no of calls, lets say if the user tries reloading the pages multi times it tend to call the same REST API multiple times right